# Как сделать перемещение картинки на передний план без увеличения?

Tags: css

Есть несколько картинок, расположенных одна под другой.
Как можно сделать, чтобы при клике на одну из картинок она
перескакивала на передний план без увеличения?

[image]

Comment: Чтобы располагалась над другими элементами:  
z-order.  
Чтобы без увеличения: сделайте, чтобы в обработке onclick не было увеличения.  
А вообще было бы лучше наверно сделать перемещение на передний план не только при клике, но и когда мышь находится над картинкой (при этом обработку клика тоже надо оставить для мобильных устройств).

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.img:hover{
    z-index:6;//перенесение картинки на шестой слой
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]